# Learning based on Vector Inputs and Scalar Output

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series, model-selection

I'm trying to fit a function of the following form to some time series data that I have...

`Z = X/(a*Y+b)`

`a` and `b` are constant values, and the form of the data for `X`, `Y` and `Z` are vectors of arbitrary length.  I'm trying to figure out how to learn the `a` and `b` values given that I have measured `X`, `Y` and `Z` values.  The tricky bit, is that although I have the full vectors for `X` and `Y`, I only have a summed up scalar value for `Z`.

I do have a fair amount of data to lean on.  My hope is that although I don't know the full `Z` vector, only the scalar sum of the values, I might be able to still, by knowing `X` and `Y`, learn the `a` and `b` constants somehow.

My question is, is there a method that would be well suited to this problem?  I feel like it would be very straightforward if `Z` was a vector, but as a scalar, it seems like a lot of information is lost.